# How can I add translate3d through jQuery while using clientX and clientY?

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet of jQuery here in which I've added the CSS: `transform: translate()`. I'm wondering if it is possible to use `transform: translate3d()` instead. How would I write this?

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   $circle.css({
      transform: 'translate(' + (e.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px)'
   });
});
```

I've tried the following as a wild guess but I'm not sure what to put at the end and it doesn't work.

```
transform: 'translate3d(' + (e.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px, ' + 'px )'
```

Can anyone help me do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an unrecognized unit (`px`, no value) as the 3rd parameter for translate3d which takes 3 parameters, x y z, as recognized by it's property name.

```
transform: 'translate3d(' + (e.clientX - half_cHeight) + 'px, ' + (e.clientY - half_cWidth) + 'px, 0px)'
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d()

Comment: Hi Chloe, thanks for your answer. I've tried this and it doesn't seem to have any effect on the object I'm trying to move. Here is a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a463ndo0/